# Error while packing keyring module with PY2APP on MAC OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-keyring, mercurial-keyring

I am making an app in python which needs to store keys. I used keyring module to store keys. 
I am using python-2.7 and osx 10.8.5 with keyring 3.2( easy_install keyring).
Code is running fine on eclipse, but when I converted code into app using py2app, it shows error of MYAPP Error open console Terminate

```
import keyring
keyring.set_password("title","section","keys")
res= keyring.get_password("title","section")
```

I included terminal response scrap when typed "python setup.py py2app" while making dist through py2app

```
byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keyring-3.2-py2.7.egg/keyring/__init__.py to keyring/__init__.pyc
creating /Users/fis/Desktop/build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/python2.7-semi_standalone/app/collect/keyring
byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keyring-3.2-py2.7.egg/keyring/backend.py to keyring/backend.pyc
byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keyring-3.2-py2.7.egg/keyring/core.py to keyring/core.pyc
byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keyring-3.2-py2.7.egg/keyring/errors.py to keyring/errors.pyc
byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keyring-3.2-py2.7.egg/keyring/getpassbackend.py to keyring/getpassbackend.pyc
byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keyring-3.2-py2.7.egg/keyring/py27compat.py to keyring/py27compat.pyc
byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keyring-3.2-py2.7.egg/keyring/util/__init__.py to keyring/util/__init__.pyc
creating /Users/fis/Desktop/build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/python2.7-semi_standalone/app/collect/keyring/util
byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keyring-3.2-py2.7.egg/keyring/util/platform_.py to keyring/util/platform_.pyc
byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keyring-3.2-py2.7.egg/keyring/util/properties.py to keyring/util/properties.pyc
byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pathtools-0.1.2-py2.7.egg/pathtools/__init__.pyc to pathtools/__init__.pyc
creating /Users/fis/Desktop/build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/python2.7-semi_standalone/app/collect/pathtools
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever solved this, but I had a similar issue on my Mac (with python v2.7.6 and py2app v0.9): the script ran fine from the command line (i.e., `python scriptname.py`), but when I used `py2app` to convert it to a `.app`, it failed.

The Console messages led me to conclude that `py2app` wasn't smart enough to include the submodules from the `keyring.backends` module.  So I explicitly imported everything there and it finally worked:

```
import keyring.backends.file
import keyring.backends.Gnome
import keyring.backends.Google
import keyring.backends.kwallet
import keyring.backends.multi
import keyring.backends.OS_X
import keyring.backends.pyfs
import keyring.backends.SecretService
import keyring.backends.Windows
import keyring
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to update to only include the files actually in `keyring.backends` (which only included kwallet, OS_X, SecretService, Windows, and fail)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the possibility to try this out locally, here's my best guess:

Try importing all the bits you'll actually need in the app, including exceptions that don't occur during "normal" execution

```
import keyring
import keyring.set_password as _unused_1
import keyring.backend
import keyring.backend.PasswordSetError as _unused_2
```

You may also require some other package at runtime, to check that, do the following:

```
$ python2.7
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep  6 2013, 09:55:21) 
[GCC 4.8.1 20130725 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> before = sys.modules.keys()
>>> import keyring
>>> middle = sys.modules.keys()
>>> keyring.set_password("a", "b", "c")
Please set a password for your new keyring
Password: 
Password (again): 
Please input your password for the keyring
Password: 
>>> after = sys.modules.keys()
#
# now the interesting bits
#
>>> set(after).difference(set(middle))
set(['struct', 'crypt', 'base64', 'binascii', 'keyring.crypt', 'encodings.base64', 'encodings.base64_codec', '_struct'])
#
# and this
#
>>> set(middle).difference(set(before))
set(['cStringIO', 'heapq', 'logging.threading', 'sre_compile', '_collections', 'logging.cStringIO', '_sre', 'getpass', 'atexit', 'keyring.backend', 'logging.os', 'operator', 'Crypto.Cipher.AES', 'logging.traceback', 'keyring.os', '_heapq', 'logging.time', 'keyring.ConfigParser', 'logging.weakref', 're', 'keyring.getpass', 'sre_constants', 'imp', 'logging.codecs', 'collections', 'logging.thread', 'keyring.imp', 'keyring.logging', 'keyring.keyring', 'string', 'keyring.util.re', 'time', 'Crypto', 'termios', 'keyring.util.escape', 'logging', 'logging.atexit', 'keyring.util', 'logging.sys', 'keyring.abc', 'Crypto.Cipher', 'ConfigParser', 'keyring.util.string', 'keyring.getpassbackend', 'keyword', 'thread', 'strop', 'traceback', 'keyring', 'weakref', 'threading', 'itertools', 'keyring.Crypto', 'keyring.sys', 'sre_parse', 'logging.warnings', 'keyring.core'])
```

You see how many modules were brought in as a result of `import keyring`, but also some more modules got brought in as a result of `keyring.set_password(...)`.

Now, most of this should be automatic with `py2app`, but some runtime dependencies can be missed.

The reason behind this is that `py2app` does something tricky when it decides which modules to include. Pretend that `keyring.set_password()` doesn't actually run at this phase. In fact if it did and `set_password` must have side effects, would you expect `py2app` to package a plain or modified module?

Comment: import keyring
keyring.set_password("title","section","keys")
res= keyring.get_password("title","section") I am using this three statements only to set and get keys. Do i need a login password also to use keyring. Please set a password for your new keyring like

Comment: do i need to set password for using keyring module. or the the three statements listed above will suffice the use of keyring. Or is there any other way to store keys(not databases) in python that can be packaged in py2app

Comment: >>> import keyring
>>> import keyring.set_password as _unused_1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named set_password

Answer (score 0):

Include  **packages='keyring.backends'** in setup.py to include all packages of keyring.